# boost::asio::streambuf -- linker error

Tags: gcc, c++11, boost-asio, linker-errors

I'm having trouble getting a boost program to compile.  The example I'm trying to compile is here:  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Web_scraping#C.2B.2B

This is what happens when I try to compile:

```
  % g++ -Wall test.c -lboost_regex  -lboost_system -lboost_thread 
    /tmp/ccJSxOji.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::length_error>::error_info_injector(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::length_error> const&)':
    test.c:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt12length_errorEC2ERKS3_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt12length_errorEC5ERKS3_]+0x53): undefined reference to `std::length_error::~length_error()'
    /tmp/ccJSxOji.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::length_error>::~error_info_injector()':
    test.c:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt12length_errorED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt12length_errorED5Ev]+0x2e): undefined reference to `std::length_error::~length_error()'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I've narrowed the problem down to this line:

```
boost::asio::streambuf response ;
```

I'm using gcc 4.6.0, linux of course:

```
% gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/src/gcc-4.6-20110429/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl --enable-cloog-backend=isl --enable-lto --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --enable-plugin --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.0 20110429 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

Possibly related thread:

[Code using boost::asio::streambuf causes segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971980/problem-with-boostasiostreambuf)

Comment: Compiles and runs for me. gcc 4.5.2, gcc 4.6.0, boost 1.42, boost 1.46.

Comment: Try adding `#include <stdexcept>` to the source file before including any Boost headers. The error makes me think it's attempting to catch with only a forward declaration of the class.

Comment: @ildjarn No go.  Same error message as before.  I'm using boost 1.46, btw.

Comment: Well, you're getting linker errors, not compiler errors; somehow you're not linking with whatever object has the definition for `std::length_error`'s destructor... Personally, I haven't been able to repro that locally.

Comment: @ildjarn cool, that helps.  I'm going to try removing my archlinux boost and boost-libs packages, followed by installing boost by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but as it turns out, I was bitten by this:  [/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

I did some more digging:

```
 % ldd /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so
/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so)
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77b3000)
        libicuuc.so.46 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.46 (0xb7553000)
        libicui18n.so.46 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.46 (0xb7389000)
        libicudata.so.46 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.46 (0xb650a000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb6501000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6412000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb63e8000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb63cc000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb63b1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb624b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb6246000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77b4000)

% ldd /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so)
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb78cf000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb788f000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb77a1000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb7777000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb775b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb773f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb75d9000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb78d0000)
```

In sum, my gcc-libs were out of date.  To fix it, I did:

```
# pacman -Q -o /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 is owned by gcc-libs 4.6.0-5

# pacman -S gcc-libs
```

Thanks to everyone who commented, you got me thinking in the right direction.